# TypeScript in JSII doesn't ignore node_modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, node-modules, jsii

I have a JSII project with following JSII section in `package.json`:

```
  "jsii": {
    "outdir": "dist",
    "targets": {
      "python": {
        "distName": "pipeline-github-token",
        "module": "pipeline_github_token"
      }
    },
    "tsc": {
      "outDir": "build",
      "rooDir": "src"
    }
  }
```

During build JSII generates `tsconfig.json` file which contains following section:

```
  "include": [
    "**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "build/**/*.ts"
  ],
```

But it looks like TypeScript still tries to process files inside `node_modules`, I am getting errors like

```
node_modules/jest-snapshot/build/index.d.ts:179:9 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

179   [hint?: string, fromPromise?: boolean]
            ~
node_modules/jest-snapshot/build/index.d.ts:179:30 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

179   [hint?: string, fromPromise?: boolean]
                                 ~
node_modules/jest-snapshot/build/index.d.ts:179:31 - error TS1134: Variable declaration expected.

179   [hint?: string, fromPromise?: boolean]
                                  ~
node_modules/jest-snapshot/build/index.d.ts:179:40 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

179   [hint?: string, fromPromise?: boolean]
                                           ~
node_modules/jest-snapshot/build/index.d.ts:180:1 - error TS1109: Expression expected.

180 >;
    ~
node_modules/jest-snapshot/build/index.d.ts:180:2 - error TS1109: Expression expected.
```

Why doesn't TypeScript ignores/excludes `node_module` content during compilation?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following:

https://github.com/aws/jsii/issues/3864

You are probably using a version of @types/jest that isn't compatible with jsii.  The current version of jsii is compatible with older versions of typescript.